# Knowing which button is clicked from previous activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have three button on one activity_A each button when clicked it start activity_B , but my Question is how to know which button is started the activity_B ?

update :

```
           btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(LastDaysActivity.this);
                prefs.edit().putString("Date1", btn1.getText().toString()).apply();


                Intent i = new Intent(LastDaysActivity.this, TabHostActivityLastDays.class);
                i.putExtra("button", "1");
                startActivity(i);



            }
        });
```

activity B :

```
        Toast.makeText(BatteryActivityLastDays.this, String.valueOf(my.getLastDaysValues(result1, 10)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    String intent = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("button");
    if (intent != null)
    {

        Toast.makeText(BatteryActivityLastDays.this , intent , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many ways to do this but probably the easiest is just by sending an `extra` with the `Intent`.

In sending class something like,

```
Intent i = new Intent(..., ...);  // obviously replace ... with the class and context
i.putExtra("button", "btn1");
startActivity(i);
```

and in receiving class

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent != null)
{
    String clicked = intent.getStringExtra("button");
}
```

you could also use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) but this may be overkill depending on what you need.

[Intent Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: then i should use if statment like: if(clicked.equal("btn1"){ // do something } .. ?

Comment: Yes, however you need to use it. You can pass a `String`, `int`, whatever you want through the `Intent`. It shows you all of the methods in the docs. If you do `if ("btn1".equals(clicked)){` it protects against a `NPE`. Make sure you don't call `getIntent()` before `onCreate()` (such as outside of a method) or it will be `null`.

Comment: thanx you very much but what do you mean by : NPE

Comment: `Null Pointer Exception`. It means that if `clicked` is `null` for some reason it won't throw an exception this way. The other way it would throw an exception.

Comment: why it return empty toast message when return "clicked" but I'm sure i have clicked on button1

Comment: Did you get your other problem solved? Where is that code at in `TabHostActivityLastDays`? In `onCreate()`?

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent extras. For example :

inside onClick method :

```
Intent activityBIntent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
activityBIntent.putExtra("button_clicked", 1);
startActivity(activityBIntent);
```

and in activityB's onCreate method :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent != null){
    int buttonId = intent.getIntExtra("button_clicked", 0);
}
```

Comment: The method getIntExtra(String, int) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String)